# How to get a simple text-only page to output onto Discord when requested with a command?

Tags: javascript, php, discord

I have a simple code I use to output the number of players on a server currently.

It's a simple print_r output, and a h3 tag.

I'd like to know how to take the contents of this website and output it on a Discord Server when requested with a command?

```html
print_r($result);
echo "Players Online";
```

That's all it is and it says it in a text-format.

Comment: did you try something so far ?

Comment: The only thing is attempting to use og:description tags, however Discord does not support no cache meta tags